# Excel count of counts

Tags: excel

If I have an Excel table as follow:

```
User1   1
User2 . 3
User3 . 2
User4 . 1
User5 . 1
User6 . 5
User7 . 2
```

I'm trying to graph the amount of similar values.
In other words, I want to show how many "1s" there are in my list (3), how many "2s" (2) etc. Ideally in bar chart. For some reason I just can't figure it out today...

Comment: What about COUNTIF? Have you tried? Also, another option would be resuming your data with a Pivot Table or even directly a Pivot Chart.

Comment: Pivot table / chart with second column as rows / category axis and first column as values.

Comment: Thanks - Pivot chart did the trick...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is like this:

[image]

Then you can create a PivotChart:

> **[Create a PivotChart](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/create-a-pivotchart-c1b1e057-6990-4c38-b52b-8255538e7b1c)**

And just take field USERS into X axis, and Count field into VALUES section. Something like this:

[image]

This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use PivotChart, you can do something like this:

[image]

1. Create an auxiliary table with unique values (use **remove duplicates**)
2. Create a bar chart with the **Count** values as a series with the **Number** values as the axis